# How to select a date connected value from database and link it to current model time in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

```
irradiance_V = (double) selectFrom(irradiance_windspeed)
    .where(irradiance_windspeed.date_time.eq(time()))
    .firstResult(irradiance_windspeed.global_irradiance)
```

I would like to select my variable global_irradiance from database table (irradiance_windspeed) if the actual model time equals the date_time value (which is connected to the specific gloabal_irradiance) from my database table.
Unfortunately Anylogic returns the following compilation problem:
"The method eq(Date) in the type SimpleExpression is not applicable fom the argument double"

I'd be very grateful if somebody could help me fixing that problem.
Thanks!

Comment: try to use date() instead of time()... but you may run into new different problems depending on how date_time is defined in your database

Comment: Thanks so far Felipe!
date_time is defined as date in the format of "01.01.2016 00:55" continued in hourly steps.
I now changed time() to date() which leads to a NullPointerException for the last line of the code above